# cs.js - displaying only one line at the same time (in multi-line chart)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm new in JavaScript, D3.js and C3.js. I have multi-line chart like [this](http://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy.html). I wonder is there any possibility in C3 to display only one line in the chart (f.e. data1). And how to switch chart to display second data and turn off any other at the same time? 
I'll be grateful for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ot19Lyt8/2/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 130, 300, 200, 300, 250, 450]
        ]
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data1',
        done: function () {
            chart.load({
                columns: [
                    ['data2', 100, 250, 150, 200, 100, 350]
                ]
            })
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alitavakoli/op1z4m0f/)

If you just want to hide lines rather than remove them altogether, you can do something like this using the API:

```
function showOnly(chart, id) {
  // get the already shown lines so we can hide them
  // (excluding our target id)
  var shown = chart.data.shown().map(function(e) { return e.id; });
  var idx = shown.indexOf(id);
  if (idx >= 0) {
    shown.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  chart.hide(shown);

  // if our target id wasn't already visible, show it
  if (idx < 0) {
    chart.show(id);
  }
}
```